# Is there any function equivalent to mapValues in ramda.js (similar to lodash)?

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

I'm using [ramdajs](https://ramdajs.com/) in my application. I have to use a utility similar to [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) of lodash. Is there already a function in ramdajs which I can use. If not, how can I implement that with other functions in ramda? (Obviously I can use nativejs to implement this but I want to use ramdajs)

Comment: like [map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's just [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map).

`map` operates on any [Functor](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/#functor), and Ramda supplies the implementations for arrays, objects, and functions, all of which are functors, and delegates to `map` methods for other types.

So you can just use `map`:

```js
const square = n => n * n

console .log (
  map (square, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})     //=> {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}

) 
console .log (
  map (toUpper, {x: 'foo', y: 'bar'})  //=> {x: 'FOO', y: 'BAR'}
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {map, toUpper} = R                                                      </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `mapObjIndexed` could do the similar things as `mapValues` but without the iteratee shorthands.

```
const users = {
   fred:    { user: 'fred', age: 40 },
   pebbles: { user: 'pebbles', age: 1 }
};
R.mapObjIndexed((value, key) => value.age, users)
```

which outputs:

```
{"fred": 40, "pebbles": 1}
```

Comment: This could more easily be written as `map(prop('age'), users)`.  You don't use the `key` value here.